# urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request - django ping_google

Tags: python, django

I am trying to ping google for updating sitemaps, but I am getting

```
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

when I do

```
python manage.py ping_google [/my-sitemaps.xml]
```

any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command should be: (without brackets)

```
python manage.py ping_google /my-sitemaps.xml
```